# Ability to deploy Python in AWS Lambda using AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python, aws-toolkit

Is there is any ability to deploy the Python 3.9 in Lambda function using AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's the actual problem?

Comment: I want to deploy the python app using AWS Toolkit using Visual Studio 2022 to Lambda Function. I want the functionality of it on the AWS Toolkit.

Comment: Yes it's doable, look around the toolkit

Comment: Ermiya Eskandary Please see the below screenshot of Visual Studio 2022, I don't have option for it, as I have install AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 1):

@Ermiya Eskandary

I need to option to deploy it on Lambda Function using the Visual Studio 2022 just like for the .NET Application.

[image]